# Must implement inherited abstract method error

Tags: java, methods, abstract-class

I'm getting an error for `Sphere.java` that says

```bash
The type sphere must implement the inherited abstract method GeometricObjects.hit(Ray)
```

Though I don't see how I am getting this error as I've defined the hit method as shown below.

Below is the `Sphere.java` code:

```
package Objects;
import Utility.*;

public class Sphere extends GeometricObjects {

    Point3d center;
    double radius;

    public Sphere(Point3d center, double radius, Color color) {
        this.center = new Point3d(center);
        this.radius = radius;
        this.color = new Color(color);
    }

    public double hit(Ray ray) {
        double a = ray.direction.dot(ray.direction);
        double b = 2*ray.origin.sub(center).dot(ray.direction);
        double c = ray.origin.sub(center).dot(ray.origin.sub(center)) - radius*radius;

        double discriminant = b*b - 4*a*c;

        if (discriminant < 0.0){
            return 0.0;
        }
        else {
            double t = (-b - Math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2*a);

            if (t > 10E-9) {
                return t;
            }
            else {
                return 0.0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the `GeometricObjects.java` code:

```
package Objects;
import Utility.*;

public abstract class GeometricObjects {
    public Color color;

    public abstract double hit(Ray ray);
}
```

And heres the `Ray.java` code:

```
package Utility;

public class Ray {
    public Point3d origin;
    public Vector direction;

    public Ray(Point3d origin, Vector direction) {
        this.origin = new Point3d(origin);
        this.direction = new Vector(direction);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try recompiling? The abstract definition looks fine, and the implementation in `Ray` also looks fine. Separately, the `Sphere` constructor calls `new Color(color)` – is that correct? Can't tell since it's not specified what type `Color` is.

Comment: Your code seems okay to me. Does adding an `@Override` annotation to the `hit` method cause any errors?

Comment: (This is really bad naming `package Objects;`) Probably you have some old classes in your compile path. Try to clean up everything and compile again.

Comment: @PeterMmm Ah thats it, thanks. Changed package name to GeometricObjects and recompiled and error was gone.